# How to get method to show in swagger?

Tags: azure

I've created a Mobile App and working through the get started at: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-xamarin-ios-get-started-preview/

I'd like to add Swagger to this app. I've added SwashBuckle (version 5.2.2), but I see no API's when I navigate to the /swagger URL.

My controller looks like this below.

```
[MobileAppController]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public string Get()
}
```

My question is:
What do I need to change so that the Get method will show up on the swagger api?

Regards,
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[MobileAppController]` attribute and see if you get the Swagger docs.  Most likely, you have overridden the Swagger config in that custom attribute.  If that's the case, you should be able to add a call to `SwaggerConfig.Register();` wherever you are setting up your `HttpConfiguration`.